# In spark what is the difference between setting the conf spark.default.parallelism and calling the method rdd.coalesce()?

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd

In spark what is the difference between setting the conf spark.default.parallelism and calling the method rdd.coalesce() ?

does both have same result ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html), `spark.default.parallelism` is the

> Default number of partitions in RDDs returned by transformations like
> `join`, `reduceByKey`, and `parallelize` when not set by user.

with a default value of:

> For distributed shuffle operations like reduceByKey and join, the
> largest number of partitions in a parent RDD.
>
> For operations like
> parallelize with no parent RDDs, it depends on the cluster manager:
>
> Local mode: number of cores on the local machine
>
> Mesos fine grained
> mode: 8
>
> Others: total number of cores on all executor nodes or 2,
> whichever is larger

The `rdd.coalesce()` method allows you to reduce the number of partitions in the RDD, for example by calling `rdd.coalesce(1)` you will reduce the number of partitions to 1.

Therefore, they generally don't give the same result, but you could imagine the setting of `spark.default.parallelism` to be similar to

```
rdd.{transformations...}.repartition({value of spark.default.parallelism})
```

after `join` or `reduceByKey` transformations.